# PHP preg_match search for specific pattern coming from a path

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to scrap some information just for learning PHP and regex and I would like to extract it from an html.

The html text is an entire webpage but it has some patterns like  *somehtmltext_andtags_andeverything* **/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=THE_ID_I_WANT** *andmore_text_and_tags*.

I can isolate the pattern with TextEdit in Mac, but I want separate it!

[image]

how could I make it in PHP?

Thank you in advance!
Rafael.

---

Sorry, I was very unclear.

I want to separate only de ID, so if you see the image, the only text you would get is **100009799451329** . If the final result is the whole sentence (*ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100009799451329*) it doesn't matter, goes fine for me!

Comment: What regex/code did you try to achieve it? What results did it get?

Comment: Sorry @mario, just edited it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$matchArr = NULL;
preg_match_all("/\/ajax\/hovercard\/user\.php\?id=(.*?)\&/", $yourStr, $matchArr);
print_r($matchArr);
```

Comment: Gave valid because of the rest of the code :)
Thanks.

Comment: Don't know why he removed his comment, but I agree with chris, fails if nothing follows `([0-9]+)` is saver than `(.*?)\&`. And if the parameters come in other order, e.g. id is not first, it's another story.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pattern to find the id:

```
\/ajax\/hovercard\/user.php\?id=(\d+)
```

See [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX2nQ6/1).

Explanation:

`\/ajax\/hovercard\/user.php\?id=` will match */ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=*

`(\d+)` captures a sequence of digits, in this case the user id.